# Overloading Assignment operator outside of class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have been trying to the overload the assignment operator outside the class using a friend class but no matter what I do it doesn't work. (yes I know the convention is to overload the operator inside the class). Heres a sample of what I have been doing to get it to work:

```
class Person{

public:

Person(string n){
     name = n;
}

friend class assignment;

name = "Joe";

}


}

class assignment{
public:
Person operator&(Person &rhs){
        Person test;
        test.name = rhs.name;
        return test;  //return *this doesn't work

        }
}
```

No matter what I do the assignment operator doesn't run/return in main:

```
Person one("Joe")
person two("Martin");
person three("Anna")

two = three;

std::cout<<two.name; //does not equal the member variable of three;
```

Comment: That doesn't compile.

Comment: What you have posted doesn't seem to make any sense. Can you explain your logic?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was possible to operator overload the assignment operator outside the class. Is it?

Comment: @anonanon no, it is not

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the code and cutting to the core of the question as stated in the comments: *I just wanted to know if it was possible to operator overload the assignment operator outside the class.* the answer is no.

**[class.copy.assign]** expressly forbids it. I only have n4618 on hand at the moment, so that's what I'll quote:

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a **non-static non-template member function** of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.

You can do all sorts of things to work around this, but they are NOT an assignment operator.